# How to store and get http form data in Azure Insights for Azure Function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have Azure Function app (v.4) with post api calls to some external rest resource. I can see occasional failures in Azure monitoring (Azure Insights), but everything I was able to collect in Logs is external api endpoint url (Path like `https://...` when you open dependencies) with the request get parameters. In order to troubelshoot the failure I need to collect Form data as well for post requests. I wonder how easy it would be, like as easy as setting some flag in azure configuration or modifying app and writing tracing logs explicitly.

Comment: The App Insights - >Transaction Search will show requests, traces but it will only indicate that your function made a HTTP `POST` call, the response of that call..it will not show the payload, your function app need to log details as `TRACE` info using `ILogger` that is injected to your function.

Comment: got it. Thank you. Please feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Insights -> Transaction Search in the portal will show the requests and trace messages but it will only indicate that the function made a HTTP POST call, the response code and duration of that call, it will not show the payload details, so the function app explicitly need to log those details as `TRACE` info using `ILogger` instance that is injected to the function.